# Use a table's specific (single) cell data

Tags: javascript, report, cell, birt

Using JavaScript, how to get a Table data and store it in an array, so that it can be used by different report item.

For example, I need to use a table's specific (single) cell data and display it using another report item.

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign data set field (or anything) to a global JavaScript variable and use it in another report item.

Having:

```
+----
|table
+----

+----
|dynamic text
+----
```

in Table `onCreate` -- initialize array:

```
myArray = new Array();
```

in Table row `onCreate` -- fill in the array:

```
myArray.push(row['MYCOLUMN']);
```

in DynamicText value -- use it:

```
myArray[0]
```