# BIRT reports, how would you create a sticker sheet?

Tags: java, eclipse, report, birt

How would I create a report that contains a page of stickers. I can get the stickers to display as a single column using a list but if I wanted to have one next to the other then how would I go about this? What control should I use and with what settings? I tried to set the properties of the list to display inline and set the height and width to the size of the sticker but what happens is all the stickers are shown on top of each other (as a single sticker)... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

http://usosphp.mimuw.edu.pl/~jankiel/pub/so-6226579.rptdesign

I've created two data sets, each has filtered even/odd rows. Then, I've created Joint Data Set which merges both.

As a result, table has simultanosely access to two table rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this wasn't what I had asked how to do. Have you any better suggestions that might solve the problem? I am using 1 dataset, I do not need to merge datasets, I need to present the data such that there is a sticker containing several pieces of data (the row from the dataset), then another sticker next to that which is the next row of the dataset, when the edge of the page is reached I need the next sticker to follow underneath the first. If each sticker is a div in html then they would have a style property of float:left or display:inline to attain this result.

Comment: Maybe this approach will suit better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216057/birt-use-a-tables-particularsingle-cell-data/6219991#6219991 . Create hidden table which extracts data do Javascript array. Then fill Dynamic Text value with div-s/span-s, using for-loop.